# Suggested resources for learning to write a Mac OS filter scheme driver

Tags: macos, process, driver, kernel-extension, hfs+

I am trying to create a Mac OS filter driver but unsure of the best up-to-date resource.

There are some chapters of the book "Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach (paperback)" online, but they appear to be a version from over 10 years old. There is a newer version available on amazon (listed as published in 2016), however I saw a rating for that book said that several hundreds of pages, and several chapters were missing.

Does anyone know if the latest paper (or E) version of this book contains detailed information about making a filter scheme driver in Mac OS X?

Someone also pointed out the KauthORama sample code as a resource, however it seem that was last updated roughly 5 years ago.

Has anyone actually made a filter scheme driver in the recent past, and if so what resources do you suggest?

UPDATE: I have gotten a response from the publisher regarding the book mentioned above. In 2016 it was made into softcover and broken into two books, but the content is from 2006. So I am doubting it will be that useful over 13 years later. They said the author didn't want to update the content.

Comment: What are you trying to do, roughly? “Filter scheme” I believe is a windows thing which doesn’t have an equivalently powerful equivalent on Mac. On Mac, block storage layer kexts may sometimes be called “filter schemes” - this is at the block/partition level, not file level though. Kauth O rama is still authoritative.

Comment: My goal is to create a custom driver that does encryption. This book refers to the term "filter scheme drivers". Am I missing something? https://books.google.com/books?id=KjX57QfgwZkC&pg=PA346&lpg=PA346&dq=%22filter+scheme+driver%22&source=bl&ots=f0Z94kMCM4&sig=CittTLgOZ67be0p8OS6UKv_8OLY&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_6KGI5N7fAhWpHzQIHRv2CwsQ6AEwCHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22filter%20scheme%20driver%22&f=false